# php exporting xls: the file format and extension of don't match

Tags: php, excel, xls

I'm exporting xls with this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.xls");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
my export
</body>
</html>
```

but when I open it, I get:
**the file format and extension of don't match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe. unless you trust its source, don't open it. do you want to open it anyway?**
is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You might want to use a library for this purpose. Try looking at [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). I tried it before and I believe the exported file doesn't show that warning.

Comment: You have embedded your content within html. Remove the html tags.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I'd prefer to avoid using external libraries,

Comment: @symcbean I tried removing the <html> tag but didn't work, if you meant all the html tags, then how do I format tables?

Comment: Your content also contains HTML tags????!!!!! You have a lot of learning to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is HTML, not an Excel file. As Excel says, the file format and extension don't match. If you want to avoid the warning message, save it as an HTML file and open it from Excel.

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.html");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
my export
</body>
</html>
```

Or output a different file format such as CSV. It's very simple.

```
<?php
$my_data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 3],
];
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attach; filename=filename.csv");
$h = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach($my_data as $data) {
    fputcsv($h, $data);
}
fclose($h);
```

Comment: So to export it with .xls extension I need a library for writing in excel format ?

Comment: Yes. But there’s nothing you’re going to get from XLS that you can’t get from CSV unless you need formulas or formatting.