# Disable Specific Excel Popup

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro that exports many files from bloomberg. However, the following error message pops up for every file:

"The file and format and extension of ______.xls don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

The usual popup disable method below does not work.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Is there any method to disable the popup or code it to enter "yes" to the popup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php exporting xls: the file format and extension of don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949837/php-exporting-xls-the-file-format-and-extension-of-dont-match)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be relevant here. I can't specify what file type to export as when I'm exporting from bloomberg.

Comment: Are you importing or exporting? Did you try either method before commenting?

Comment: I am exporting the data from bloomberg using VBA. As such, there is no way to specify what file format it is exported as

Comment: Can you rename the file and use the correct extension?

Comment: Would help to show the code which runs the exports.

Comment: Relevant Registry keys and values: https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=excel16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_Forcefileextenstionstomatch   and https://www.onepager.com/support/faq.php?id=93   If you disable extension hardening (assuming that's the cause here) then I wouldn't leave it that way after you're done with this task...